# Missing GrailsDependencies?

Tags: grails, ggts

I am getting the following error when importing the project into GGTS:

> Grails Dependencies [2.0.1] (uninitialized).

I could see, the problem is similar to which is raised in one of the issue
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/springsource-tool-suite/115801-missing-grailsdependencies

Comment: May you please provide more details like what is your grails version etc.